# Why I can't run this programs in terminal?

Tags: linux

Ubunntu 16.04 fresh updated.

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 piotr piotr   4096 sep 14 02:59 platform-tools
-rw-r--r--  1 piotr piotr  17408 aug 16 13:09 PrimaryGPT.gpt
-rwxr-xr-x  1 piotr piotr 201204 júl 15  2016 qflash
-rw-r--r--  1 piotr piotr 358048 jan 15  2015 sbl2_tmp.mbn
drwxr-xr-x  3 piotr piotr   4096 feb 27  2020 sdat2img

piotr@piotr-Ex:~/lg$ qflash
qflash: command not found
```

> [image]

Comment: You don't have `.` in your `PATH`? Does it work if you type `./qflash`?

Comment: Please don't edit answers in attempt to reply. That's what comments are for. Also, I've edited my answer yesterday to explain why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 7):

Unlike Windows, Linux will not run executables from current directory by default. You could enable this behavior by adding `.` to `$PATH`, but it would have additional security implications and I'd recommend not doing it.

To call an executable that's not in `$PATH` you have to specify the path explicitly. Rather than just the filename, enter file's path. Assuming you're in `~/lg` where the file is located, that would be `./qflash` (`.` always refers to the current directory).

If you're eg. in `~`, you could call `lg/qflash` (relative path) or `~/lg/qflash` (absolute path - independent from current directory). This may not always work though, because some programs make use of the directory you're currently in.